# Run a java class for a plain java project from Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have an android studio (1.3) generated Java Library project. It has a single class:

```
package com.me.test;

public class Hi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi.");
    }
}
```

I have setup an 'Application' Run Configuration for this class. The settings from the config file are all chosen via the IDE picker, I have not filled in any manually:

```
Main class: com.me.test.MyClass
Working Directory: parent folder (tried every sub folder as well)
Use classpath of module: MyOneAndOnlyModule
```

When I run the configuration, it works ok once. Running it a second time, I get a ClassNotFoundException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  com.me.test.Hi
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    ...
```

I uninstalled android studio, downloaded ok, and can run the configuration ok once. The second time starts failing again.

I just want to be able to run a java class from within android studio without having to reinstall the IDE each time.

Right-clicking the class in the project tree, then choosing the run config also results in the same class not found exception.

Thanks